# Windows Mobile 6 emulator

Tags: character-encoding, emulation, hebrew, windows-mobile-6

I am developing some applications in [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) 6 on [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008), and I need to show some information in Hebrew, but my emulator doesn't show that language. Instead it shows very strange characters. How do I set Hebrew font in my emulator, so that I will be able to see Hebrew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice the [Windows Mobile 6 Localized Emulator Images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=38C46AA8-1DD7-426F-A913-4F370A65A582&displaylang=en) doesn't include Hebrew so you may need to install your own font to the emulator and then reference that font from your application.

To install a font on Windows Mobile, check out [How To Add New Fonts to your Windows Mobile Device](http://www.careace.net/2009/05/18/how-to-add-new-fonts-to-your-windows-mobile-device/).

Comment: I added a link that describes how to install a font on Windows Mobile, nisnis84.

Comment: what about win7? the link is specific to xp!